# Trying to read URL from Edge, Process.MainWindowHandle = 0 for "MicrsoftEdge.exe" Process

Tags: c#, microsoft-edge, automationelement

I'm trying to write an Edge -> Chrome service, so i'm using a ManagementEventWatcher to create an "edge started" event.

From the event i get the processId, from the processId i get the Process, and from the process i get the Main window handle.

What's annoying is, when i set the event watcher to watch for MicrosoftEdgeCP, i get a main window handle, when i set it to MicrosoftEdge i get nothing.

I tried to navigate the MicrosoftEdgeCPs using AutomationElement (thinking i may be able to pull the url from that), but when i use .FindAll(TreeScope.Children, Condition.TrueCondition) i get zero children.

So i'm calling it a night for now, any suggestions would be warmly appreciated :)

Comment: Why don't you use EdgeDriver and ChromeDriver? Here is the command to get current URL from Edge: https://w3c.github.io/webdriver/webdriver-spec.html#dfn-get-current-url

Comment: That was the first thing that i tried, but i'm fairly sure you can only use the driver with a new edge session.

Comment: Although waaaay past my bedtime, i carried on for a bit (currently operating on four hours), I used the "getByPoint" and set the point in roughly the right area. That appears to work, looks like this window doesn't actually have a handle since the AutomationElement has zero for the window handle.